# How to check which var is right in JS?

Tags: javascript

```js
var first_name = "Shaunak";
var lastName = "Gujjewar";
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = first_name;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = lastName;
```

```html
<h1><tt>JS is case sensitive.</tt></h1>
<p>
  JS is case sensitive,in the example given below you will undertand that <b>JS does not accept var as VAR/Var</b>. Indeed it will accept only the <b>CamelCase/var with underscore and a hyphen</b>. But hyphen is not usually preffered as it is a reserved
  function for <b>subtraction</b>.
</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Now the problem I am facing is when I typed this code and executed it,it only displays my lastName but not my first_name.So which changes should I bring in this code so that JS can display both first_name & lastName. Also if JS is case sensitive then how to identify the right variable ?

Comment: just put document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = first_name + ' ' +lastName;

Comment: It's normal, you replace the html inside "demo" by the first_name var, and then you replace it again with your last_name

Comment: Off topic, but the stuff about hyphens in the text is nonsense.

Comment: the `<tt>` tag isn't valid in HTML5

Comment: @Kypaz I didn't get you !!

Comment: @Shaunak check martincarlin87 answer

Comment: @Juhana I just checked the http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_syntax.asp. The site mentions that hyphen is used for subtraction. Is it right ?

Comment: @Shaunak Yes, that part is (almost) right (it's an operator, not a function), but you can't use it in variable names.

Comment: @Juhana Sorry but I couldn't get you please show me some example ! ( I just started learning programming ) Sorry if I am annoying you

Comment: No, you're not annoying, but it's unclear what exactly you don't understand. I'm just saying that *"Indeed it will accept only the CamelCase/var with underscore and a hyphen"* is wrong because it will **not** accept a hyphen.

Comment: @Juhana You mean that an hyphen is not accepted in var declaration right ?

Comment: A hyphen is not accepted in var declaration.

Comment: @Juhana  Ok. So how do we choose the right var or can you suggest me a better var in the program mentioned above ?

Comment: What are you talking about? You don't have any hyphens in the variable names. There's nothing wrong with what you have there.

Comment: Ok. I will make the changes that you have suggested.

Comment: If you want to know which one of these type of variable naming you "should" use: it depends on your environment. In most cases (and arguably best practice in javascript) would be to go with `camelCase`. But often you work with data responded from a server where you'll find `snake_case` to be used more often. More importantly, choose whatever you like, but stick with it throughout your project if possible.

Comment: @lexith Please give me an example of snake_case and camelCase ( just for reference ) !!!

Comment: *silently cries under the shower*

Comment: I didn't get you ? Is that an example or are mocking me ?

Comment: No i really was crying. Okay, seriously now: `camelCase`: thisIsCamelCase. `snake_case`: and_this_would_be_snake_case. For naming of files `kebab-case` often-comes-to-use.html but not as variable naming.

Comment: hiMyNameIsShaunak-CamelCase.

Comment: Yay! Depening on your environment (again), sometimes (for example in c#) you use UpperCaseCamelCase for variables. And one last thing, if you see something like _thisVariableHere it is meant that this variable is private in its context (but still camelCase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overwriting `first_name` when it's inserted into `demo` by replacing the contents with `lastName`.

You could concatenate them first:

```
var first_name = "Shaunak";
var lastName = "Gujjewar";
var name = first_name + ' ' + lastName;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = name;
```